# Pandas failing to read pickle file, returning NoneType

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I am working with some relatively heavy data that is stored in CSV files and the time it is taking to read in to my DataFrames with read_csv is becoming rather untenable, so I decided to implement a pickle cache since they load so much faster.  I seem to have the caching working, as the files have good sizes on them by comparison to their CSV counterparts as seen below:
[image: Local Files]

The issue is that when I try to read them back in, I get this:

[image: Failure State]

The code I am using is pretty simple:

```
self.path = ".".join(path.split(".")[:-1]) + ".pkl"
def saveCache(self, df = False):
    with open(self.path, "wb") as f:
        if df:
            df.to_pickle(f)
        else:
            self.data.to_pickle(f)

def readCache(self):
    with open(self.path, "rb") as f:
        self.data = pd.read_pickle(f)

print(f"Here is the data from {rawTaskDataSet.path}\n", rawTaskDataSet.data)
```

I have used a similar setup elsewhere in my code and it worked flawlessly.  I was originally not using the filestreams and simply passing the self.path to DataFrame.to_pickle() and pd.read_pickle(), but switched in a desperate attempt to see why it was failing.  As you can see, everything is to and from the exact same paths and there are no errors, but for some reason I am getting None types, which is obviously crashing all of my other code.

Error using .parquet files at the request of @Corralien
[image: parquet error]

Comment: Please provide the code where you print *Here is the data from ...*. If you replace `to_pickle` and `read_pickle` with `to_parquet` and `read_parquet` after installing `pyarrow`, does your code work?

Comment: @Corralien I will edit with the line that prints out the "here is the data from" line, though it is pretty much straight forward.  I will also attempt the parquet setup after I edit for that.

Comment: @Corralien Nope, same thing.  Editing with the updated error.

Comment: It's possible for you to provide a minimal reproducible example, please? With the class, the `__init__` method and its usage?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. `self.data` does contain nothing. Try with a minimal example to check if it works.

Comment: I can try tomorrow (it is midnight here), but I will have to take care as there is proprietary data involved in the init.